# Google Sheets API POST request

Tags: http, post, google-sheets-api, esp8266

I am always getting -1 as a response from the `httpClient.POST` method, don't you know why? If I try to POST to another endpoint (not Google API), everything works fine.

```cpp
void sendMeasuredData() {
  Serial << "Sending data to Google Sheets" <<endl;
  StaticJsonBuffer<250> JSONBuffer;
  JsonObject& JSONencoder = JSONBuffer.createObject();

  JSONencoder["range"] = "Measurements!A1:C1";
  JSONencoder["majorDimension"] = "ROWS";

  JsonArray& values = JSONencoder.createNestedArray("values"); //JSON array
  values.add("TIMESTAMP"); //Add value to array
  values.add(temperature); //Add value to array
  values.add(humidity); //Add value to array

  char JSONmessageBuffer[250];
  JSONencoder.prettyPrintTo(JSONmessageBuffer, sizeof(JSONmessageBuffer));
  Serial << JSONmessageBuffer << endl;

  HTTPClient httpClient;
  httpClient.begin("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/values/Measurements!A1:C1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED","F9:C3:81:B3:84:13:E8:94:87:B1:87:6D:8A:15:75:27:09:56:93:BE");

  httpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpClient.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+access_token);  

  int httpCode = httpClient.POST(JSONmessageBuffer); 
  String payload = httpClient.getString();
  Serial << "GoogleSheets Response: " << httpCode << endl;
  Serial << payload << endl;

  httpClient.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you read from the sheet?

Comment: Actually yes, i can even write into the sheet, but only via Postman. And when I use another endpoint in my code (for example zapier webhook), everything works properly.

Comment: Been playing with this and think it's because of https:// not http:// Try an http enpoint and see if that works maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add ?key at the end.